# Is there a deescalation protocol or procedure between the U.S. and China?

Tags: united-states, china, international, international-relations

Is there a deescalation protocol or procedure between the U.S. and China? I am wondering if there's a protocol or procedure agreed upon by the U.S. and China for preventing an all-out war between the U.S. and China. If no procedure or protocol is agreed upon, is there a procedure or protocol the U.S. would use to deescalate a war with China?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [something roughly analogous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing%E2%80%93Washington_hotline) to the [Moscow Washington hotline](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/hotline-established-between-washington-and-moscow) during the Cold War.

> The Beijing–Washington hotline is a system that allows direct communication between the leaders of the United States and China. This hotline was established in November 2007, when China and the United States announced that they will set up a military hotline between Beijing and Washington D.C. to avoid misunderstanding during any moments of crisis in the Pacific.

There are allegations that China is playing hard to get with it.  If true, that's quite worrying because political posturing is not its purpose.